# How do I make sure that the person has a certain item from the shop?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, quick.db

I've had this problem for hours where I can't make sure that people have bought a pet before doing activities with it.

It doesn't show an error but it doesn't work properly and I don't know how to reference a certain item in a player's inventory because I'm trying to implement a pet feature where you can fight pets with other people and also will be able to feed your pet and there will be events like pet races and stats etc.

```js
const db = require('quick.db');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {

  name: "fight",

  description: "fight someone",

  async run(client, message, args) {
    let target = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (!target) return message.channel.send('please provide a person to fight');
    let user = message.author;
    let theitemsofuser = await db.fetch(message.author.id, {
      items: []
    });
    if (target === user) return message.channel.send('You can\'t fight yourself!')


    if (db.has(user.id + !'.items.hamster')) return message.channel.send('you need a pet to fight');
    if (db.has(user.id + !'.items.dog')) return message.channel.send('you need a pet to fight');
    if (db.has(user.id + !'.items.cat')) return message.channel.send('you need a pet to fight');

    if (db.has(target.id + !'.items.hamster')) return message.channel.send('your opponent needs a pet to fight');
    if (db.has(target.id + !'.items.dog')) return message.channel.send('your opponent needs a pet to fight');
    if (db.has(target.id + !'.items.cat')) return message.channel.send('your opponent needs a pet to fight');


    message.channel.send('your all good!')
  }

}
```

Comment: `user.id + !'.items.hamster'` why is there a `!` before the string? o.O

Comment: Perhaps he mean `if(!db.has(user.id.items.hamster))`

Comment: i mean that if they don't have items.hamster it says you dont have a pet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string concatenation is wrong. There shouldn't be an exclamation mark before the strings after target.id.

If you do this, it'll concatenate the truthy value, converted to a string, so 'false' in this case.

What you have right now (bad)

```
'test' + !'string'
// >> 'testfalse'
```

What you need (good)

```
'test' + 'string'
// >> 'teststring'
```

It should work if you just remove the ! from db.has

Answer (score 0):

Try this construct

```js
async run(client, message, args) {
  ...
  const match = { 
    userPet : "",
    targetPet : ""
  }

  ["hamster","dog","cat"].forEach(pet => {
    if (db.has(user.id.items[pet])) match.userPet = pet
    if (db.has(target.id.items[pet])) match.targetPet = pet 
  });
  if (!match.userPet) { message.channel.send('You need a pet to fight'); return }
  if (!match.targetPet) {message.channel.send('Your opponent needs a pet to fight'); return; }

  message.channel.send('your all good!')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using this code :

````
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {

name:"fight",

description:"fight someone",

async run (client, message, args){
let target = message.mentions.users.first();
if(!target)return message.channel.send('please provide a person to fight');
let user = message.author;
let theitemsofuser = await db.fetch(message.author.id, { items: []});
 if(target === user) return message.channel.send('You can\'t fight yourself!')


if(!db.has(user.id + '.items', 'hamster'))return message.channel.send('you need a pet to fight');
if(!db.has(user.id + '.items', 'dog'))return message.channel.send('you need a pet to fight');
if(!db.has(user.id + '.items', 'cat'))return message.channel.send('you need a pet to fight');

if(!db.has(target.id + '.items', 'hamster'))return message.channel.send('your opponent needs a pet to fight');
if(!db.has(target.id + '.items', 'dog'))return message.channel.send('your opponent needs a pet to fight');
if(!db.has(target.id + '.items', 'cat'))return message.channel.send('your opponent needs a pet to fight');


message.channel.send('your all good!')
}}```
Fixes: I used !db.has(user.id + '.items', 'dog') return message.channel.send('you dont have a dog at the moment') Instead of db.has(user.id + '.items', 'dog') return message.channel.send('you dont have a dog at the moment')
````